# Differnt page template for page 2 of blog feed

Tags: templates, blog, paged

Is there a way I can use one page template (A custom page template for example) for the first page of my blog and then another template (Index.php for example) for page 2, 3, 4, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you can use a complete different template but you can use different template parts using the global $page variable.

Example:

```
global $page;

    if ( $page == 2 ) {
    get_template_part( 'page', 'two' );
} else {
    get_template_part( 'page', 'default');
    }
```

This would load the template file page-two.php or page-default.php depending on what page you were on.